# Hibernate: How to list all mapped objects?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

How can I inspect at run time what Hibernate has setup for object mappings?

I have a mapping that is not generating any errors,it is in the hibernate config, but yet it is not being found.  I want to inspect the mappings to verify that it is there and also check for typos.

Comment: How do you know it's not being found? Are inserts not working? What exactly is happening?

Comment: Jeff, I figured it out. It indeed wasn't be found - in the query I was using the casing of the table name not the object name.  DOH!

Comment: the confusing part to me that I've used the object name along with the field names. I suppose I can see a reason for this, but it's still confusing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the metadata of all the entities using [SessionFactory.getAllClassMetadata()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#getAllClassMetadata%28%29).